# Редирект с сайта на проект MVC

Tags: php, mvc, редирект

Есть папка со старым сайтом test/, необходимо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку перебрасывало на сайт, написанный на MVC test/localhost/, но при попытке сделать это вылезает ошибка
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method controllers\IndexController::localhost() in C:\OSPanel\domains\test\localhost\conf\route.php:65 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\test\localhost\conf\config.php(15): conf\Routing::buildRoute() #1 C:\OSPanel\domains\test\localhost\index.php(4): require_once('C:\OSPanel\doma...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\test\localhost\conf\route.php on line 65"
Содержимое файла route.php:

```html
<?php

namespace conf;

use controllers\CabinetController;
use controllers\CanteenController;
use controllers\IndexController;
use controllers\MonitoringController;
use controllers\ProfileController;
use controllers\UsersController;

class Routing
{

    public static function buildRoute() {

        /* Контроллер и action по умолчанию */
        $controllerName = "IndexController";
        $modelName = "IndexModel";
        $action = "index";

        $route = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));

        $i = count($route)-1;

        while($i>0) {
            if($route[$i] != '') {
                if(is_file(CONTROLLER_PATH . ucfirst($route[$i]) . "Controller.php") || !empty($_GET)) {
                    $controllerName = ucfirst($route[$i]) . "Controller";
                    $modelName =  ucfirst($route[$i]) . "Model";
                    break;
                } else {
                     $action = $route[$i];
                }
            }
            $i--;
        }

        //var_dump($controllerName);

        //$controller = new $controllerName();
        $controller = null;
        switch ($controllerName) {
            case 'CabinetController':
                $controller = new CabinetController();
                break;
            case 'CanteenController':
                $controller = new CanteenController();
                break;
            case 'IndexController':
                $controller = new IndexController();
                break;
            case 'MonitoringController':
                $controller = new MonitoringController();
                break;
            case 'ProfileController':
                $controller = new ProfileController();
                break;
            case 'UsersController':
                $controller = new UsersController();
                break;
        }

        if ($controller) {
            $controller->$action();
        }
    }

    public function errorPage() {
        header("Location: /404.php");
    }

}
```

Содержимое index.php:

```html
<?php
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

require_once ('conf/config.php');
```

Содержимое config.php:

```html
<?php

/*Общие константы приложения*/

session_start();
define("ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define("CONTROLLER_PATH", ROOT . "/controllers/");
define("MODEL_PATH", ROOT . "/models/");
define("VIEW_PATH", ROOT . "/views/");
define("UPLOAD_FOLDER", ROOT. "/uploads/");
define("UTILS", ROOT . "/utils/");

use conf\Routing;

Routing::buildRoute();
```

Пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: А что не ясно из описания ошибки? Метод localhost есть?

Comment: Нет, я впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, даже примерно не понимаю что должен содержать этот метод.

Comment: Этот метод должен существовать, как минимум. Его у вас нет

Comment: Если его не предполагается, то нужно сделать глобальный обработчик ошибок и страницу 404

Answer (score 0):

Реализуйте метод `localhost` в классе `IndexController`, тогда ошибка пропадёт.

Если достаточно простое перенаправление на целевой адрес, то можно воспользоваться перенаправлением средствами HTTP.

Как пример реализации метода `controllers\IndexController::localhost()` для перенаправления средствами HTTP:

```php
class IndexController
{
  ...
  public function localhost()
  {
    header('Location: /test/localhost/', true, 302);
  }
  ...
}
```

Что бы всё работало максимально корректно, в заголовке Location должен участвовать полный URL, а не только его `path`-часть (как в примере).

Если же перенаправление должно быть кешируемым, то можно заменить `302`-й код ответа на `301`, но не советую этого делать пока работа не будет оттестирована.

Comment: Вылезает ошибка 
"Объект не найден!
Запрашиваемый ресурс не найден. Ссылка на странице неверна или устарела. Пожалуйста, сообщите автору этой страницы об ошибке.

Если Вы считаете, что это ошибка сервера, пожалуйста, сообщите об этом веб-мастеру.

Error 404
test
Apache"
В чем же все-таки дело?

Comment: На каком именно URL происходил описанная ошибка? На старом (`/test`) или уже на новом (`/test/localhost`)?

Comment: На новом /test/localhost

Comment: Тогда это уже вопрос почему нет обработчика или маршрута на обработку этого пути. Само перенаправление, как и требовалось, работает.